# Insert a string into a string at a specific point using PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm wondering if there is a way to insert a string into another string at a specific point (in this case, near the end)? For example:

```
$string1 = "item one, item two, item three, item four";
$string2 = "AND";

//do something fancy here

echo $string1;
```

OUTPUT:
**item one, item two, item three, AND item four**

I need some help with the fancy string work part. Basically inserting the word after the last ", " if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace for this, and I find it to be terser than other string manipulation methods and also more easily adaptable if your use case should change:

```
$string1 = "item one, item two, item three, item four";
$string2 = "AND";

$pattern = "/,(?!.*,)/";
$string1 = preg_replace($pattern, ", $string2", $string1);

echo $string1;
```

Where you pass preg_replace a regex pattern, the replacement string, and the original string.  Instead of modifying the original string, preg_replace returns a new string, so you will set `$string1` equal to the output of preg_replace.

The pattern: You can use any delimiter to signal the beginning and end of the expression.  Typically I see / used*, so the expression will be "/pattern/", where the pattern consists of the comma and a negative lookahead (?!) to find the comma that isn't followed by another comma.  It isn't necessary to explicitly declare $pattern.  You can just use the expression directly in the preg_replace arguments, but sometimes it can be just a little easier (especially for complex patterns) to separate the pattern declaration from its use.

The replacement: preg_replace is going to replace the entire match, so you need to prepend your replacement text with the comma (that's getting replaced) and a space.  Since variables wrapped in double quotes are evaluated in strings, you put $string2 inside the quotes**.

The target: you just put your original string here.

* I prefer to use ~ as my delimiter, since / starts to get cumbersome when you deal with urls, but you can use anything.

Here is a cheat sheet for regex patterns, but there are plenty of these floating around.  Just google regex cheat sheet if you need one.

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Also, you can find plenty of online regex testers.  Here is one that includes a quick reference and also lets you switch regex engines (there are a few, and some can be just a little bit different than others):

https://regex101.com/

** I prefer to also wrap the variable in curly braces to make it more explicit that I am inserting the value, but it's optional.  That would look like `", {$string2}"`

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this - but since you specifically stated "after the last `,`" then `strrpos` seemed appropriate:

```
// insert this line where you indicate 'do something fancy here'
$string1 = substr_replace($string1, " ".$string2, strrpos($string1,",")+1, 0);
```

> Find the right-most comma and insert the `$string2` (with a space prepended) one position after it.  The last parameter indicates the length of the substring to replace so a `0` means "do not replace anything but only insert."

Note the extra space added to `$string2`.  Obviously you could modify how `$string2` is initialized to include the space and eliminate this part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern to match the last comma in the string using `.*,` and then use `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

In the replacement use  `AND`

```
$string1 = "item one, item two, item three, item four";
$string2 = " AND";
$string1 =  preg_replace("/.*,\K/", $string2, $string1);
echo $string1;
```

Output

```
item one, item two, item three, AND item four
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/SWfr0).